# Windows Run can't find batch file

Tags: python, windows, batch-file

I created a very simple batch file that works when I double click the file, but if I try to launch it by typing in the name of the batch file into Windows Run, Windows is unable to find it. If I type in the name of the folder containing the batch file, the folder opens up.

Fairly new to coding. I'm going through "Automate the Boring Stuff" book

Comment: WIN+R starts in your `%userprofile% directory. Where is your script, and where is the folder located?

Comment: In Run their is a _Browse_ button. Browse to your file and it will fill in the right path to type. Then it will be in the history in Run.

Answer (score 2):

Run searches the folders in your global `%PATH%` variable for your file. It's unlikely that your script is in one of the directories mentioned in `%PATH%`.

To see the contents of PATH, type `ECHO %PATH%` into a command prompt. You can then move your script to one of the directories.

Alternatively, to temporarily (for the current CMD session) add a directory to PATH, run `SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\path` in your command prompt. A permanent change in PATH requires use of the registry.

I recommend you reconsider this approach however, as launching CMD then navigating to the script's location (`CD C:\path`) to then run the script is generally preferable to changing global variables.

Comment: Hey, just trying to figure things. Windows Run is able to find the folder containing my batch file, but it can't find the batch file itself. Shouldn't it be able to run the file in the folder if it can open the folder?

Comment: What do you mean by "find the folder containing the batch file"? If you're typing the path to the folder into Run, it'll open the path using Explorer. Likewise, if you're typing the full path of your batch file into Run, it'll open the batch file directly. If you only type in a filename, it'll search for that filename as I described in my answer.